# Advice with letters of recommendation etiquette

Tags: recommendation-letter

I'm applying to graduate school and require two letters of recommendation. However, I'm not sure what the best process is for asking for these letters. I plan on asking two or more of my superiors (there's about 5-6 total), and believe that while all of them will be positive, some may have better writing skills.

Should I ask based on my order of preference? Or simply ask all of them to write one, if they're willing and have the time? Or should I send out an e-mail stating my situation and requests? I'd like some advice on how to handle the situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual process is that *you* actively approach those that you think will write you the best letter. In practice, you will want to engage the advisors that are the best trade-off between the following, sometimes conflicting, criteria:

- Prefer **people that know you, your work, and your skills in detail** over people that you don't know that well. Specifically prefer people that know you from research projects or other "outside the classroom" activities. Letters that only say "ASimonis01 had an A in my class" are not worth much.
- Prefer **people that are willing to write you a very strong letter** over people that may write a more lukewarm recommendation. This should be obvious, but keep in mind that everybody does that, so the overall level of enthusiasm in letters is *very* high. Even a well-reasoned positive-ish letter with some negative aspects may already be a kiss of death for your application.
- Prefer **people that are in a position to write a plausible recommendation**. In practice, this usually means that more senior and/or more well-known recommenders are better than less experienced ones, simply because a statement like "among the best student I have had" means much more if the writer is a senior professor than an assistant prof. in his first year.
- Prefer **people who know how to write a recommendation letter**. Especially if you are currently located in a different cultural region, it is well possible that your letter writers are not overly familiar with how a recommendation letter is *supposed* to be written. The end result may be a letter that is *meant* to be positive, but which is perceived as lukewarm or unprofessional. In the same context, avoid like the plague people that you suspect may just submit a stock letter.
- Prefer **academics over pretty much anybody else**. That is, don't get recommendations from your boss in industry, your coworkers, or your childhood friend. The reason is the same as above - you want letters from people that are able to judge whether you will be a good grad student. Your boss in industry can't do that. Researchers in industry research labs may qualify, but I would still prefer a professor in almost all cases.

Also note that at least in the US one generally does not get to *see* the written letters, they are uploaded by the recommender directly. This means that you need to be very careful in your selection, as you cannot pivot after receiving a suboptimal letter from one of your references.